# Creating reusable objects with Raphael

Tags: raphael

I'm stuck on a simple problem (I just started using the lib):

What is the most effective way to create sets of objects, replicate them and transform them?

Creating a bunch of circles around a center point:

```
var height = 150,
    width = 150,
    branchRadius = 20,
    centerX = width / 2,
    centerY = height / 2,
    treeCrownCenterOffset = 10,
    treeCrownRotationCenterX = centerX,
    treeCrownRotationCenterY = centerY - treeCrownCenterOffset,
    rotationCenter = [treeCrownRotationCenterX , treeCrownRotationCenterY],
    paper = Raphael('logo', height , width ),
    outerCircle = paper.circle(treeCrownRotationCenterX, treeCrownRotationCenterY, branchRadius).attr({fill:'#F00'}),
    innerCircle = paper.circle(treeCrownRotationCenterX, treeCrownRotationCenterY, branchRadius - 4).attr({fill:'#000'}),
    branch = paper.set([outerCircle, innerCircle]),
    crown = paper.set(),
    numCircles = 8, rotationStep = 360 / numCircles, i = 0;

for(; i < numCircles - 1 ; i++) {
    //Cloning a branch and pushing it to the crown after transforming it
    crown.push(branch.clone().transform('r' + ((i + 1) * rotationStep) + ',' + rotationCenter));

}

//Putting a second crown 200px right of the first crown
//Yes, I'm building a tree :-) No trunk at this point

crown.clone().transform('t200,0');​​​​​
```

If you like violin, here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzSvA/42/).

This is my naive code, thinking a set of cloned sets (the crown of cloned branches) will indeed be moved to position (200, 0), next to the first crown.

It doesn't work: looks like a cloned set of cloned elements cannot be moved:

```
crown.clone().transform('t200,0');​
```

Not much happens when this line is executed.

Seems like "cloning" is not doing what I expect, and that the transformations are not carried to the second (cloned) collection of objects.

The basic question is:

How does one go about creating reusable objects with Raphael?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are cloning the set, but since your canvas is only 150px wide, translating it by 200 pixels is sending it off the reservation :)

When you do expand the size of the canvas, however, you will see that only one circle appears to have been cloned. This is not the case. The problem is not with the cloning but the transformation.

I find transformations to be a huge headache. The line "crown.clone().transform('t200,0');​" is applying that transformation to each object in the set, but *I believe* it is overriding the rotation. Even if it weren't, it would be applying the translation after the rotating, sending the circles scattering as if by centrifugal force.

I know you wanted to avoid looping through the cloned set, but this works:

```
var crown2 = crown.clone();
for (i = 0; i < crown2.length; i ++) {
    crown2[i].transform('t200,0r' + (i * rotationStep) + ',' + rotationCenter);
​}​
```

Also, note that you didn't add the original branch to the set. You need this:

```
branch = paper.set([outerCircle, innerCircle]),
crown = paper.set(),
numCircles = 8, rotationStep = 360 / numCircles, i = 0;

//ADD ORIGINAL BRANCH TO SET
crown.push(branch);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzSvA/51/).

Comment: Thank you kindly. Appreciated much the Fiddle update. You say "I find transformations to be a huge headache", and I concur. The cumulative effect of successive transformations is difficult to "debug".  When trying to "import" paths from Inkscape, containing both transformations and matrices, than trying to code around that...  well :-)

Comment: +1 for "sending it off the reservation."  And I concur with respect to transformations: they are powerful, but the room for unanticipated complexity is extremely frustrating at times.